# Simple if statement Batch

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I tried running the code but it doesn't seem to work. How do I make the code work?

```
@echo off
SET /P choice= What do you want me to do?:
if %choice%==shutdown (
SET /P time= In how many minutes shall I shut down the computer?: 
set /a "time=%time%*60"
shutdown -s -t "%time%"
) elseif (

)
```

Comment: You should **delay expansion** inside a block. You should not really change the value of a **system environment variable** either.

Comment: What's `elseif`, and what's the point of this empty branch??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my comments.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set /P "Choice= What do you want me to do?: "
If /I "%Choice%"=="shutdown" (
    Set /P "Span= In how many minutes shall I shut down the computer?: "
    Set /A Span *=60
    ShutDown -S -T !Span!
) Else (If

)
```